# spark-submit failed due to Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop

I got the error information below when i tried to submit my spark job for testing purpose.

```html
jianrui@spark:~$ sudo $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit --class com.test.spark.FirstScalaExample --master spark://spark.sparkstreaming.i10.internal.cloudapp.net:7077 /opt/spark/FirstScalaExample-0.0.1.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.test.spark.FirstScalaExample.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:42)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2018-04-06 13:13:00 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-04-06 13:13:00 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-7f47cab1-f8b3-4731-bd67-e0d0ad013617
```

[Scala version - 2.11.6]
[Hadoop version - 2.7.5]
[Spark version - 2.3.0]
Note:
To be informed that i specified the hadoop native lib in this way "export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native" in the "spark-env.sh", and i only extract the spark but not installed. 
I don't know what exactly the problem is.

Comment: is there a main function in com.test.spark.FirstScalaExample class?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Yes, the main function does exit in the class "com.test.spark.FirstScalaExample" class.

Comment: can we see the definition of main method?